# With a Scala Either, how do you stop at the first error, but gets the already computed values

Tags: scala, functional-programming

For example, let say I have a function

```
def foo(): Either[String, Int] = ???
```

I want to call this function 3 times. If all the values are `Right`, I want the sum. If I have one `Left`, I want to get the error and the sum of all previous `Right` values (~ stop the computation at this point).

the only way I found to do this is :

```
List(foo, foo, foo).foldLeft((None, 0)) { 
  case ((Some(err), sum), _) =>  (Some(err), sum)
  case ((None, sum), fn) => fn() match {
    case Left(err) => (Some(err), sum)
    case Right(x) => (None, sum + x)
  }
}
```

Is there some generic functional programming feature (with cats or scalaz for example) to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Stream.span`:

```
val (ints, rest) = Stream.continually(foo()).take(3).span(_.isRight)

val sum = ints.map(_.right.get).sum
val error = rest.headOption
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same solution with tail recursive function:

```
 def sumRights(allFoos: List[() => Either[String, Int]], accum: Int = 0): (Option[String], Int) = {
    allFoos match {
      case Nil => (None, accum)
      case head :: tail =>
        head() match {
          case Right(x) => sumRights(tail, accum + x)
          case Left(err) => (Some(err), accum)
        }
    }
```

Another imperative solution is to split on a first Left with `splitWhere`, and sum up all values of first output list.

Comment: Your tail recursion doesn't satisfy the requirement of lazy evaluation of `foo` : "~ stop the computation at this point".

Comment: Indeed! Rewritten to accept list of function instead of list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if scalaz of cats have something specifically for this, but here is how you can solve this in vanilla scala:

1. lazy Stream:

   ```
   Stream.continually(foo()).take(3) match {
     case s =>
       val err = s.collectFirst {
         case Left(err) => err
       }
       val sum = s.takeWhile(_.isRight)
         .flatMap(_.right.toOption)
         .sum

       (err, sum)
   }
   ```

`Stream` will be calculated lazily and cached.

2. Tail recursion:

   ```
   def rec(sum: Int = 0, i: Int = 2): (Option[String], Int) =
     if (i < 0) (None, sum) else foo() match {
       case Left(e) => (Some(e), sum)
       case Right(s) => rec(s + sum, i - 1)
     }
   ```